# Where can I find Android's onDestroy() method

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-application

I'm developing an App using React-Native. I have implemented a Camera package, but when I take a picture, the pictures are not saved to my temporary gallery. I'm given an error in the console which leaves me to believe that the problem is that I need to first delete the existing cache directory, so that a new one can be created. Error below

> 5:59:08 PM: [Error: Directory
>   'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fsurf-app-4cd0edb5-6a9f-4172-b7a4-9d7df74efccb/photos'
>   could not be created.] Directory exists

From my prior investigation, I have concluded that I need to find the `onDestroy()` method and re-write it. Do I need to download an android application on my PC that will allow me to navigate to the file that holds this method? How does one find and edit the `OnDestroy()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand you problem. Is it an Android related issue?

`onDestroy()` method is one of the most common life cycle event for an Android application. If you are building an app using `Fragment` or `Activity`, you can easily find this method inside these class, thus it won't be that difficult if you want to override this method in you custom fragment or activity class.

Comment: It sounds like the onDestroy() method is written uniquely for each application? This makes more sense. I guess what I need to do is figure out why my application is not deleting this directory as it supposed to; not rewrite some method that exist on my phone.